# is there a way to pass extra data to MyApplication_UnhandledException event handler?

Tags: vb.net, design-patterns, .net-3.5

I am creating a design pattern for non developers and I am incorporating a catch all error handler with the UnhandledException event. I'd like to write the error out to a log file but the log file name has a time stamp in it, so it will change with each run. Is there a way my handler can receive or access the log file name string?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually the UnhandledException event handler is located in the class that contains your startup code. So there is nothing to prevent you to define a shared public variable in this class that contains the name of your logfile. You could initialize its value at startup reading from a configuration file. Then inside the event is possible to use that variable to open your log file and write your information

EDIT: in your scenario you could try this pseudocode

```
Partial Friend Class MyApplication

    ' the name for the log file
    Public logName As String

    Private Sub MyApplication_UnhandledException(sender As Object, e As Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.UnhandledExceptionEventArgs) Handles Me.UnhandledException
        Dim ex As Exception = e.Exception
        If Not ex Is Nothing Then
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
            Using sw = new StreamWriter(My.MyApplication.logName)
               .....
            End Using
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

and in your intial form add this call to define the logName

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    My.Application.logName = "C:\temp\text.txt"
    ' as test
    Throw New Exception("This is an unhandled exception")
End Sub
    End Sub
```

Comment: visual studio 08 wants you to drop it here

Namespace My


    Partial Friend Class MyApplication
        
        Private Sub MyApplication_UnhandledException(ByVal sender As Object, _
                                                     ByVal e As Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.UnhandledExceptionEventArgs) _
                                                     Handles Me.UnhandledException
           End Sub
    End Class

End Namespace